# Want to rename a file through windows batch file scripting

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-rename

Here is my file MY_APP_CON_123_yyyymmdd.hhmmss.txt where "yyyymmdd.hhmmss" is variable data. I want to rename it to MY_APP_CON_0123_yyyymmdd.hhmmss.txt (Zero infront of 123). When I use ren command as shown below, the first y disappears from the file name.

```
REN MY_APP_CON_123_* MY_APP_CON_0123_*
```

Any solutions ?

Comment: `for %%a in  (MY_APP_CON_123_*) do set "name=%%a" & ren !name! !name:123=0123!`

Comment: Thanks Aacini I modified it a bit as shown below for %%a in (MY_APP_CON_123_**) do set "name=%%a" & ren %name% %name:123=0123%

Comment: @Aacini - your solution fails on December 30 (and 31). In a general sense, you should not assume the substring does not appear multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

Not answer, but explaining why your rename isn't working:

cmd.exe/command.com's wildcard renaming is position based, e.g.

```
filename: abc123.txt
command: ren abc*.txt abd1*.txt
```

will do:

```
abc123.txt    - original name
||||**.txt
abd1**.txt    - rename pattern
----------
abcd23.txt    - new filename
```

https://superuser.com/questions/475874/how-does-the-windows-rename-command-interpret-wildcards

Wildcard renaming where you want to change parts of the filename and the new part has a different length from the original part gets very hairy.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pure batch solution.

```
@echo off
for %%F in (MY_APP_CON_123_*) do @set "name=%%F"&call ren "%%name%%" "%%name:*MY_APP_CON_=MY_APP_CON_0%%"
```

Or, with delayed expansion:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for %%F in (MY_APP_CON_123_*) do @set "name=%%F"&ren "!name!" "!name:*MY_APP_CON_=MY_APP_CON_0!"
```

But I would use my [JREN.BAT regular expression renaming utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6081) - a hybrid JScript/batch script that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward.

```
call jren "^MY_APP_CON_123_" "MY_APP_CON_0123_" /i /fm *.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for %%a in (MY_APP_CON_123_**) do set "name=%%a" & ren %name% %name:123=0123%
```

This worked for me

Comment: This will fail on December 30 (and 31). This is not a good solution.

Comment: Also, this cannot work at all because `%name%` will have the value that existed (if any) before the loop is executed. That is why Aacini used delayed expansion in his comment.